# Trying to get database information to another page

Tags: php, mysql

So i have a project and we need a database for it. This database is filled with information and it is shown on the website. (I use HTML, CSS, PHP, jQuery & MySQL.)

This website is about ordering concert tickets. So when I, as customer, go to the page with all the concerts listed, there's a button behind it that will take me to the order page. In that order page, I can choose which concert to go to and then proceed. The next page has the name of the customer shown and the concert. Here you type the amount of tickets you want and then it calculates how much you have to pay.

Here's the thing: When you're on the "showAllConcerts" page, and you press the button behind the 3rd concert, I want it to take the customer to the page where you tell the website how many tickets you want. In other words, when you press the order button, I want it to skip the "chooseConcert" page and have the correct concert on the page after that.
("allConcerts" -> "chooseConcert" -> "chooseTicketAmount" = "allConcerts" -> "chooseTicketAmount") You get what i mean.

Now, there's probably an easy solution for this, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Maybe you can hire someone to do the job...that's the best answer to this kind of question ;)

Comment: I don't really have the time for that.

Answer (score 0):

You may pass concert identification to the "Choose ticket amount" page as a GET parameter. But I agree with Robert Rozas comment.

Answer (score 0):

cookies, localStorage, sessions, passing through GET or POST as a (serialized) param.

Upvote for Robert Rozas